# How can i correctly print out this dictionary in a way i have each word sorted by the number of times(frequency) in the text?

Tags: python-2.7

How can i correctly print out this dictionary in a way i have each word sorted by the number of times(frequency) in the text?

```
slova = dict()
    for line in text:
        line = re.split('[^a-z]',text)
        line[i] = filter(None,line)
        i =+ 1
    i = 0
    for line in text:
        for word in line:
            if word not in slova:
                slova[word] = i
                i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `text` looks like, and you also haven't provided example output, but here is what my guess is. If this doesn't help please update your question and I'll try again. The code makes use of `Counter` from  `collections` to do all the heavy lifting. First all of the words in all of the lines of the text are flattened to a single list, then this list is simply passed to `Counter`. The keys of the `Counter` (the words) are then sorted by their counts and printed out.

CODE:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
text = ['hello hi hello yes hello',
        'hello hi hello yes hello']

all_words = [w for l in text for w in re.split('[^a-z]',l)]
word_counts = Counter(all_words)

sorted_words = sorted(word_counts.keys(),
                      key=lambda k: word_counts[k],
                      reverse = True)

#Print out the word and counts
for word in sorted_words:
    print word,word_counts[word]
```

OUTPUT:

```
hello 6
yes 2
hi 2
```